# Include toBeCloseTo in Jest .toMatchObject

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm testing that an object matches a set of fields, but one of them is floating point and I need to use [.toBeCloseTo](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/expect#tobeclosetonumber-numdigits). How can that be done within one [expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/expect)?

```
expect(foo).toMatchObject({
  bar: 'baz',
  value: ???.toBeCloseTo(5),  // TODO
});
```

I could use `expect(foo.value).toBeCloseTo(5)`, but I don't want to break the logic into multiple `expect`s, one for each floating point number.

Comment: `expect(foo.value).toBeCloseTo(Math.round(foo.value));` something like this, I guess.

Answer (score 18):

### Issue

The [docs for `toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) states "You can match properties against values or against matchers".

Unfortunately, `toBeCloseTo` is not currently available as an asymmetric matcher, it looks like [these are the only asymmetric matchers currently provided by Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c01b4c75a2f65e9fa122adf69b0ac11875f1fc74/packages/expect/src/index.js#L324-L337).

---

### Solution

If you are using Jest v23 or higher you can create your own, essentially duplicating [`toBeCloseTo`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c01b4c75a2f65e9fa122adf69b0ac11875f1fc74/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L87-L102) using [`expect.extend`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers):

```js
expect.extend({
  toBeAround(actual, expected, precision = 2) {
    const pass = Math.abs(expected - actual) < Math.pow(10, -precision) / 2;
    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () => `expected ${actual} not to be around ${expected}`,
        pass: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `expected ${actual} to be around ${expected}`,
        pass: false
      }
    }
  }
});

const foo = {
  bar: 'baz',
  value: 4.9999
};

test('foo', () => {
  expect(foo.value).toBeAround(5, 3);  // SUCCESS in Jest > v20
  expect(foo).toMatchObject({
    bar: 'baz',
    value: expect.toBeAround(5, 3)  // SUCCESS only in Jest > v23
  });
});
```

Note that `expect.extend` creates a matcher that can be used within functions like `toMatchObject` only in Jest v23 and higher.

---

### Alternate Solution

From [this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4711#issuecomment-337236678) by a Jest collaborator: "Although it is implied but **not currently documented**, Jest assertions evaluate asymmetric matcher objects as [defined in Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite#section-Custom_asymmetric_equality_tester)".

An asymmetric matcher using [the logic from `toBeCloseTo`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c01b4c75a2f65e9fa122adf69b0ac11875f1fc74/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L90) can be created like this:

```js
const closeTo = (expected, precision = 2) => ({
  asymmetricMatch: (actual) => Math.abs(expected - actual) < Math.pow(10, -precision) / 2
});

const foo = {
  bar: 'baz',
  value: 4.9999
};

test('foo', () => {
  expect(foo).toMatchObject({
    bar: 'baz',
    value: closeTo(5, 3)  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting, if `false` is passed as [the second argument on this line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c01b4c75a2f65e9fa122adf69b0ac11875f1fc74/packages/expect/src/index.js#L378) then Jest v23 [creates asymmetric matchers](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c01b4c75a2f65e9fa122adf69b0ac11875f1fc74/packages/expect/src/jestMatchersObject.js#L58-L99) for all of the built-in matchers making it possible to use `toBeCloseTo` within `toMatchObject`.  I might open up an issue to ask why `true` is being passed there.

Comment: Thanks! I've added this answer to [the discussion on adding a `toBeNear` matcher to `jest-extended`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/issues/145).

Comment: Thoughts on the [general case of using matchers in .toMatchObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556712/using-jest-matchers-in-tomatchobject)?

Comment: interestingly, their docs shows examples where [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) is used in asymmetric way

Comment: How to get those nice jest `expect(received).toEqual(expected)` messages?

Comment: This is great. I also updated it to require a `difference_allowed` param instead of `precision` and have the output indicate how much the value was supposed to be within, like `expected ${ actual } not to be within ${ difference_allowed } of ${ expected }`.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript support can be added to Brian's answer with:

```
export {};
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Expect<R> {
      toBeAround(actual: number, expected: number, precision?: number): R;
    }
  }
}
```

in a jest.d.ts file.