# Using Jest matchers in .toMatchObject

Tags: jestjs

<sup>This question is the general case for [Include toBeCloseTo in Jest .toMatchObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369407/include-tobecloseto-in-jest-tomatchobject).</sup>

How can I use any [Jest extend matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) within the [`.toMatchObject(object)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) matcher?

For example, testing that an object has several fields, including a field `foo` > zero:

```js
expect({ a: 'b', c: 'd', foo: 3 }).toMatchObject({
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
  foo: expect.toBeGreaterThan(0),  // expect.toBeGreaterThan is not a function
});
```

I know I could write `expect(theObject.foo).toBeGreaterThan(0)`, but is there away to not break away the logic for testing `.foo` from the `.toMatchObject` call?

Comment: Wouldn't the techniques in the answer you previously received work for all the other matchers that aren't available asymmetrically? What else do you hope to get for the "general case"?

Answer (score 1):

I know, very late. Combining `toBeOneOf` and `toBePositive` worked for me:

```
expect({ a: 'b', c: 'd', foo: 3 }).toMatchObject({
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
  foo: expect.toBeOneOf([0, expect.toBePositive()]),
});
```